# Java LocalDateTime conversioning with mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, mybatis

### Environment

- mybatis-spring-boot-starter 2.0.1
- mybatis 3.5.1
- mybatis-spring 2.0.1
- mysql-connector-java 8.0.16

jvm timezone : Asia/Seoul

---

My test query

> SELECT #{from}, #{to}

Input

```java
YearMonth input = YearMonth.of(year, month)
LocalDateTime from = input.atDay(1).atStartOfDay()
LocalDateTime to = input.atEndOfMonth().atTime(LocalTime.MAX)
```

---

Case1. add `serverTimezone=UTC` into jdbc url

Case1. add `serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul` into jdbc url

```sql
[11:03:54] [main] [DEBUG] BaseJdbcLogger.debug(143)| ==>  Preparing: SELECT ?, ? 
[11:03:54] [main] [DEBUG] BaseJdbcLogger.debug(143)| ==> Parameters: 2020-01-01T00:00(LocalDateTime), 2020-01-31T23:59:59.999999999(LocalDateTime)
[11:03:54] [main] [DEBUG] Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.sqlTimingOccurred(368)|  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
1. SELECT 2020-01-01T00:00, 2020-01-31T23:59:59.999999999
 {executed in 3 msec}
[11:03:54] [main] [INFO ] Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.resultSetCollected(610)| 
|----------------------|----------------------|
|2019-12-31 15:00:00.0 |2020-01-31 15:00:00.0 |
|----------------------|----------------------|
|----------------------|----------------------|
```

```sql
[14:27:16] [main] [DEBUG] BaseJdbcLogger.debug(143)| ==>  Preparing: SELECT ?, ? 
[14:27:16] [main] [DEBUG] BaseJdbcLogger.debug(143)| ==> Parameters: 2020-01-01T00:00(LocalDateTime), 2020-01-31T23:59:59.999999999(LocalDateTime)
[14:27:16] [main] [DEBUG] Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.sqlTimingOccurred(368)|  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
1. SELECT 2020-01-01T00:00, 2020-01-31T23:59:59.999999999
 {executed in 4 msec}
[14:27:16] [main] [INFO ] Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.resultSetCollected(610)| 
|----------------------|----------------------|
|2020-01-01 00:00:00.0 |2020-02-01 00:00:00.0 |
|----------------------|----------------------|
|----------------------|----------------------|
```

---

Q1. Is java LocalDateTime converted to jdbc TIMESTAMP with mybatis LocalDateTimeTypeHandler?

Q2. Does mybatis LocalDateTimeTypeHandler convert value based on jdbc servertimezone setting?

Q3. Why my `2020-01-31T23:59:59.999999999` value converted to `2020-02-01 00:00:00.0`?

---

Comment: What exactly is the data type of your column?

Comment: @Basil Bourque It's `datetime`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- A1. No, MyBatis does not convert `LocalDateTime` to `java.sql.Timestamp` since version 3.5.1 (it did in the earlier versions, though).
- A2. No, MyBatis just passes the value to the driver. You can check the [type handler implementation](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/c0da59636db3dcfbe4eddf32e7a8586df35c913a/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/LocalDateTimeTypeHandler.java) yourself.
  It is actually the driver that performs the conversion and the behavior is filed as a bug on their tracker.
  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93444
- A3. While Java's `LocalDateTime` has nanoseconds (9 digits) precision, MySQL's `TIME`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` only have microseconds (6 digits) precision. And the behavior you observed is explained in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html).

  > Inserting a TIME, DATE, or TIMESTAMP value with a fractional seconds part into a column of the same type but having fewer fractional digits results in rounding.

Comment: Point A1 has been really helpful!
Thanks for the brief yet clear explanation.